# Postgresql, how to convert an array like string to array

Tags: postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL table, one column of type text contains data like '{123456,345678}'.
Is there a way in PostgreSQL to convert this to an array?

Comment: A convoluted stored procedure parser? If you're brave you can use [PLV8](https://github.com/plv8/plv8) which gives you a whole JavaScript runtime, where parsing this is trivial.

Comment: So source is Postgres and destination is also Postgres, but an array of ints/text? Are you doing ad-hoc conversions (per query) or creating a new column and persisting converted data?  Either way, there is a way to create a new array from text as long as you trust the text is in the right format. But if you have some values that are array-like and some that are not, that will be harder to implement.

Comment: Check out [string functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html). Specifically, `string_to_array` (to split at comma) coupled with `replace` (to remove braces).

Comment: have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57961339/convert-string-to-array-postgresql

Comment: You can cast it: `'{123456,345678}'::int[]`

Comment: It already looks like an array of integers, this works fine: SELECT CAST('{123456,345678}' AS INTEGER[]);